# Double line in foreach loop with powershell?

Tags: powershell, loops, foreach

I've a list of VM like that :

```
"VmName"
"VM1"
"VM2"
"VM3"
"VM4"
"VM5"
"VM6"
```

My current script is :

```
$List_VM = Get-Content "D:\XXX\XXX\List_VM.csv" | select -Skip 1 # -Skip 1 to skip the header "VmName"

foreach($VM in %List_VM){
Write-Output $VM.replace('"', '')
}
```

The output is :

```
VM1
VM2
VM3
VM4
VM5
VM6
```

But if I put this command in my foreach Loop :

```
foreach ($VM  in $List_VM) {

Get-VM -Name $VM.Replace('"', '') | Select-object Name,
   @{N = 'vCenter'; E = {([system.uri]$_.ExtensionData.Client.ServiceUrl).Host}},
   @{N = 'Tags'; E = {(Get-TagAssignment -Entity $_).Tag -join ';'}}  

}
```

I've this output :

```
Name          vCenter                 Tags                                                                                     
----          -------                 ----                                                                                     
VM1           XXX                     Tag1/My_tag_1;Tag2/My_Tag_2;Tag3/My_Tag_3
VM1           XXX                     Tag1/My_tag_1;Tag2/My_Tag_2;Tag3/My_Tag_3
VM2           XXX                     Tag1/My_tag_1;Tag2/My_Tag_2;Tag3/My_Tag_3
VM2           XXX                     Tag1/My_tag_1;Tag2/My_Tag_2;Tag3/My_Tag_3
VM3           XXX                     Tag1/My_tag_1;Tag2/My_Tag_2;Tag3/My_Tag_3
VM3           XXX                     Tag1/My_tag_1;Tag2/My_Tag_2;Tag3/My_Tag_3
VM4           XXX                     Tag1/My_tag_1;Tag2/My_Tag_2;Tag3/My_Tag_3
VM4           XXX                     Tag1/My_tag_1;Tag2/My_Tag_2;Tag3/My_Tag_3
VM5           XXX                     Tag1/My_tag_1;Tag2/My_Tag_2;Tag3/My_Tag_3
VM5           XXX                     Tag1/My_tag_1;Tag2/My_Tag_2;Tag3/My_Tag_3
VM6           XXX                     Tag1/My_tag_1;Tag2/My_Tag_2;Tag3/My_Tag_3
VM6           XXX                     Tag1/My_tag_1;Tag2/My_Tag_2;Tag3/My_Tag_3
```

I don't understand why there is two lines for each VM in this loop while the first loop with just the print of the $VM variable gives each VM name one time...

I can put a -Unique at the end of the command but the command is twice as long as without...

There is someone to explain why ?

Comment: Its possible you've two connections, do you get two responses when you run `Get-VM -Name "VM1"` outside of the loop?

Comment: sadly can't reproduce as I have no vsphere running here, but in addition to the previous comment: use import-csv to read your inputfile instead of get-content. by doing so you do not need to skip the header and also not to replace quotes. once you import the file by using import-csv you can access the name by specifying the attribute vmname, e.g.:

$vms = import-csv "D:\XXX\XXX\List_VM.csv"
get-vm -name $vms.vmname

Comment: You can use `ConvertFrom-Csv` to parse the header and remove quotes automatically, e.g.: `gc infile.txt | convertfrom-csv | % { get-vm -name $_ | ...}`